# OData V4 WebAPI routing convention for 'Cast'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

Building an ODataController with a base Get method for the following query:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/Bases
```

is quite straightforward:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(new List<Base>());
}
```

In the same style, I'm trying to implement the "cast" route ("~/entityset/cast"), which is defined in the [OData V4 convention part 4.9](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793786) but this is quite undocumented. So I dug into some [source code](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/Conventions/EntitySetRoutingConvention.cs) and found that for the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/Bases/MyNamespace.DerivedA
```

I could define the following method in the same controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetFromDerivedA()
{
    return Ok(new List<DerivedA>());
}
```

Which works BUT I have like a dozen types that inherit from `Base`. Instead of declaring one method per derived type, is there a way I could use something like:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetFrom<T>()
    where T : Base
{
    return Ok(new List<T>());
}
```

I'm using:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3
- Microsoft.OData 6.13.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.6.0

---

### Updates

I can create [a new RoutingConvention](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions) and have the overriden SelectAction return my generic method, but it seems I'll have to forget the generic method approach:

> "Cannot call action method `'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetFrom[T]()'` on controller 'MyProject.Controllers.BasesController'
>   because the action method is a generic method."

How about this then, is this possible?

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetFrom(Type derivedType)
{
    //snip!
}
```

If not, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way I've been able to accomplish this, with a bit of reflection. It's quite a long way but the resulting controller method is so simple, it's worth it.

First, create a new RoutingConvention. Notice we'll be forwarding all cast requests to a method named `GetFrom` :

```
public class CastRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/cast")
        {
            HttpMethod httpMethod = controllerContext.Request.Method;
            var collectionType = (IEdmCollectionType)odataPath.EdmType;
            var entityType = (IEdmEntityType)collectionType.ElementType.Definition;

            var type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                .SelectMany(a => a.DefinedTypes)
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == entityType.FullTypeName());

            controllerContext.RouteData.Values["type"] = type;

            if (httpMethod == HttpMethod.Get)
                return "GetFrom";
            else if (httpMethod == HttpMethod.Post)
                return "PostFrom";
            else
                return base.SelectAction(odataPath, controllerContext, actionMap);
        }
        else
            return base.SelectAction(odataPath, controllerContext, actionMap);
    }
}
```

Next, add it to the OData configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder() { Namespace = "Default" };
    builder.DataServiceVersion = Version.Parse("4.0");

    //snip! entity configuration

    var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
    conventions.Insert(0, new CastRoutingConvention());

    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName:"ODataRoute", 
        routePrefix: "api",
        routingConventions: conventions,
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

Now, because the default model binders will not read arbitrary parameter names from the route data dictionary, we need [a custom model binder](https://gist.github.com/lencharest/b8194a014a11e09cdba6) for route data:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;

namespace Example
{
    public class RouteDataModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            object model;

            if (!actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue(bindingContext.ModelName, out model))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"No route data named '{bindingContext.ModelName}'.");
                return false;
            }
            else if (!bindingContext.ModelType.IsAssignableFrom(model.GetType()))
            {
                try
                {
                    model = Convert.ChangeType(model, bindingContext.ModelType);
                }
                catch
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"Route data cannot be converted to type '{bindingContext.ModelType.FullName}'.");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            bindingContext.Model = model;
            return true;
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class RouteDataAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
    {
        public RouteDataAttribute()
        {
            this.BinderType = typeof(RouteDataModelBinder);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, add the needed method in the controller. Notice how trivial it is:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetFrom([RouteData]Type type)
{
    var ofType = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod(type);
    return Ok((IQueryable<Base>)ofType.Invoke(null, new object[] { this.Context.Bases }));
}
```

Since I'm using Entity Framework and I can't use `GetType()`, I have to use another reflection trick to call `OfType<T>()` with a `Type` instance. If you're working with in-memory entities, just scrap the last part and use a plain:

```
return Ok(inRamEntities.Where(e => e.GetType() == type));
```

Comment: Suggestion: Do the `CastPathSegment` -> CLR type resolution in `SelectAction` and store the type on `controllerContext.RouteData.Values`. Then, in your controller action, you can either grab the type from the route data, or declare the derived type as a parameter as you originally intended.

Comment: Great idea! I'm almost there, but I can't figure out how to add a parameter :/

Comment: If I do this: `controllerContext.RouteData.Values["type"] = type;` and the controller method is: `GetFrom([FromODataUri]Type type)` type is always null

Comment: I get a value when I remove FromODataUri, and change the type to string:  `GetFrom(string type)` but that defeats the whole purpose!

Comment: Ok I guess I have to use `GetFrom([FromUri]Type type)` but then I get an error saying _cannot create an abstract class_. `Type` is indeed an abstract class.

Comment: Your type is stored on the route data, so don't use `[FromUri]` or `[FromODataUri]`. However, it turns out that the default model binders will not read arbitrary parameter names from the route data dictionary. You will need a [custom model binder for route data](https://gist.github.com/lencharest/b8194a014a11e09cdba6). Now you can write `GetFrom([RouteData]Type type)`.

Comment: Will this work for a GET request? There are some situations where a custom model binder is only used with POST requests

Comment: Great! It works!! I've updated the answer with your comments and code. Feel free to optimize it some more! Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you get this.Context.Bases?

Comment: It is the DbSet which you want to call OfType on. Just replace it with your own.